# Field in model is 'undefined' inside objects.filter()

Tags: python, django

In my model, I have a DateField called 'expire_date'.  I have a function that queries my model:

```
def date_delta_days(earlier_date, later_date):
    return (later_date - earlier_date).days

class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = """ Manages list expiration.  If lists are expiring soon, sends an email warning the list owners
               If a list has expired, the .pck file associated with that list is deleted
           """

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        now = datetime.now()
        expiring_lists = ListEntry.objects.filter(
            date_delta_days(now, expire_date) # <------ error is on this line
        )
```

When I write this, I get a syntax error claiming that expiration_date is unrecognized even though it is defined as a field in my ListEntry model.  Is there something I am missing here?  This seems like it would be a trivial query to write in SQL.

Here is my Model definition:

```
class ListEntry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    # active_date = models.DateTimeField('date of last list activity')
    expire_date = models.DateField('date of expiration')
    create_date = models.DateField('date created')


    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
```

Here is the relevant error code:

```
File "/home/jared/projects/list_expiration/list_app/management/commands/check_lists.py", line 19, in handle
    date_delta_days(now, expire_date)
NameError: global name 'expire_date' is not defined
```

Comment: can we get the full traceback?

Answer (score 2):

In your filter, you pass a positional argument - probably a timedelta, that is returned from time_delta_days. In that function you use two variables: a datetime object, returned by *datetime.datetime.now()* and... here's the cause of your problems. You're passing a variable named *expiration_date*, that is most probably undefined at that point.

What you probably want to do, is to use named arguments, as this is what *filter()* works with. Because datetime fields are comparable, you can use the *__gt* and *__lt* keywords (and other supported logical operators). You want to find *ListEntry* objects that will expire in less than 30 days from now, then use:

```
month_from_now = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=30)
ListEntry.objects.filter(expiration_date__lt=month_from_now,
                         expiration_date__gt=datetime.datetime.now())
```

I've added a second filter argument, just to make sure you're not looking at *ListEntry* objects that have already expired. You can easily adapt this code to your needs.